# My ajax process is repeating at dropzone js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I need some detail with image in the database. I am using dropzone js for upload. Problem happening when I execute more than one to ajax. After the first execute, each time its adding same data once again. dropzone working correctly

e.g 
first post adding one data -
second post adding two data -
third post adding three data

```
Dropzone.options.seferekle = {
    paramName: "file",
    parallelUploads : 1,
    acceptedFiles: '.jpg,.jpeg,.JPEG,.JPG,.png,.PNG',
    autoProcessQueue : false,
    addRemoveLinks : true,
    init: function() {

        myDropzone = this;

        $('.post').on('click', function(event){

            tarih = $("input[name=tarih]").val();

            if(!tarih)
            {
                alert("Sefer Tarihi ve Sefer Türü Alanları Boş Bırakılamaz.");
            }
            else
            {
                myDropzone.processQueue();

                myDropzone.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
                    newImgName= responseText;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/vipumre/App/Model/add.php",
                        data: "image_name="+newImgName+"&tarih="+tarih,
                        type: "post",

                        success: function(data) {
                            $('.return').show();
                            $('.return').text(data);
                        },

                        error: function() {
                            $('.return').show();
                            $('.return').text("Ajax Error");
                        }

                    }); //Ajax End

                    myDropzone.on("complete", function(file,done) {
                        this.removeAllFiles(true);
                        done();
                    })

                });

            }

        });

    } //Dropzone init End

}; //Dropzone End
```

Comment: `myDropzone` - looks like a global variable (no var declaration) - haven't checked the rest, but global variables can be a killer in asynch code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send data while you uploading your files you should use the sending event :

```
Dropzone.options.seferekle = {

    init: function (e) {

        var myDropzone = this;

        // Event to send your custom data to your server
        myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, data) {

            // First param is the variable name used server side
            // Second param is the value, you can add what you what
            // Here I added an input value
            data.append("your_variable", $('#your_input').val());
        });

    }
};
```

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer fix your problem don't forget to accept my answer.